# Webcomic with a superhero with an open relationship and an evil Walt Disney

Tags: story-identification, super-hero, webcomics

I'm pretty sure I read this webcomic in the 21st century. It involved a super-strong guy. He looked different, maybe made out of rock? He had a longterm girlfriend, as well as another girl who hung around (I want to say that the second girl had long dark hair), might have been living at the house. At some point, he establishes to the second girl that it's an open relationship. Some time after that (I think...), the three of them are in Disneyworld and an evil Walt Disney shows up to fight him along with, I think, a villainous barbershop quartet. Somewhere in the course of the fight, the secondary girl got bitten by a giant snake, causing the protagonist to fight more seriously. I think that she recovered eventually, but she was initially near death.

The general impression I remember was that the guy wasn't terribly heroic, that he'd prefer to just spend his life in peace, but people kept showing up to challenge him.

Comment: I originally read the title as "an open relationship *with* an evil Walt Disney". Naturally, I clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of a webcomic called Gregor.  http://gregor-comics.com . Doesn't match your description exactly but might be worth a look.

Comment: That would be the one. I did misremember details. The old-timey bad guys were not a barbershop quartet, and were trying to break into Walt's apartment. The snake is there. And the extra girl was with the girlfriend, not the grey guy (who apparently is not made of stone). Thank you!

Comment: Oof... and reading further, she's not even his girlfriend, just a friend. Go figure.