# Webcomic with an episode where a group of supervillains based off of David Bowie show up

Tags: story-identification, super-hero, webcomics

I was watching *Labyrinth* today and it suddenly made me remember a webcomic I read, probably five years ago, where a group of supervillains were all incarnations of various David Bowie personas. The only ones that have remained with me was the Jareth the Goblin King one (who of course wielded various balls telekinetically), one based on Ziggy Stardust (honestly, I only really recognized it due to the makeup), and one based on "[Diamond Dogs](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Music/DiamondDogs)" whose gimmick I want to say had something to do with cybernetic enhancement. Ah, and I think one of them commanded [Spiders from Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiders_from_Mars). Unfortunately, I don't remember the hero of the piece, although I remember he took them down pretty quickly.

The comic itself was kind of comedic, not gory. The art was well-executed, not realistic or too exaggerated. I think the comic was in color, at least that storyline. And the villains might have been attacking in a mall?

Comment: "The comic itself was kind of comedic...."  Wow!  I never would have expected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a storyline like this in the webcomic [Gregor](http://www.gregor-comics.com/) in 2013-2014.

The group of villains included Jareth the Goblin King, Ziggy Stardust, Major Tom, Pierrot, and two Diamond Dogs, and Ziggy summons some Spiders from Mars during the fight.  They first appear in [this strip](http://www.gregor-comics.com/comic/fashion/).

The fight took place in a bank, not a mall.  The comic was black and white at the start of that storyline, and switched to color in the middle.

Comment: Bingo! Ironically, [that means this isn't the first time I've asked about this webcomic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111313/webcomic-with-a-superhero-with-an-open-relationship-and-an-evil-walt-disney)...